# What is the meaning behind HOMRA motto?

Tags: k-project

Every time HOMRA are about to battle, they always shouting "No Blood! No Bone! No Ash!" Does it have any meaning? Somehow I can relate "ash" to their burning power. (but it's just my assumption, and I don't know about the other)

Comment: I think the idea is that when you set a person on fire, blood or bones (or ash) could be left behind. The motto, then, expresses the idea that HOMRA should burn people so thoroughly that none of those things even remain.

Answer (score 1):

HOMRA (吠舞羅, *homura*). It's not 炎, the spelling is different.

The Arabic word "حمرة" which means "redness" must be the origin, it is the red clan after all, and the spelling is identical. (try the speaker button on Google Translate for the pronunciation)

In season 2 episode 3, Kismet is from an Arabic origin as well.

Comment: 炎 has an alternative reading of "[homura](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%8E)" too. And according to Google translate, the spelling for "حمرة" is "hamra", not "homra", but the pronunciation is almost indistinguishable for non-Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

"No blood, no bone, no ash" is the saying that the red king's clan yell out before battle. It is to say that they will leave no blood, no bone nor any ash behind. It is related to their burning power.

Answer (score 0):

The saying ***"No Blood! No Bone! No Ash!"*** can mean a few things like the power that the red clansmen have or just the sheer strength that they have, but I think  it means that they leave nothing when they pass or that they have no regrets (I have no idea if any of these are correct)

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se], a Q&A site for anime. We're a bit different than other sites that we're not a discussion forum (you can take a quick [tour] to understand how this site works). Aside from that, personal opinion is acceptable *if* it can be backed up by some sources/references or more extensive explanation (if you yourself doubt your answer, how can other readers trust it). You can always [edit] your post to improve it.